# GetScopedService does not exist in the namespace ToSic.Sxc.Services, are you missing an assembly reference?

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

In 2sxc, trying to replace some old Factory/Render code in a clone of a site that is currently running DNN 9.10.02 and 2sxc is upgraded to v14.00.00.

I was doing the same thing as your [recent blog article, Deep DNN Skin and Module Integration](https://2sxc.org/en/blog/post/deep-dnn-skin-and-module-integration-towel-day-2022), the old way like this (from late 2019 or so)

```
<script runat="server">
// get 2sxc to Render() the output from the module on the SITE/Manage Flyout Links page
private string RenderFlyoutMenu()
  {
    // return ToSic.SexyContent.Environment.Dnn7.Factory.SxcInstanceForModule(419, 36).Render();
    return ToSic.Sxc.Dnn.Factory.CmsBlock(36, 419).Render();
  }
</script>
<%=RenderFlyoutMenu() %>
```

I am in `Main.ascx` theme file. To get started I figure I could just reuse the tab and module id from above in your example code from the blog and it would just work, so

```
<%@ Import Namespace="ToSic.Sxc.Dnn" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="ToSic.Sxc.Services" %>
<%= this.GetScopedService<IRenderService>().Module(36, 419) %>
```

However, I get this error.

```
Could Not Load Theme: /Portals/_default/skins/accutheme/Main.ascx, 
Error: C:\...\www\Portals\_default\skins\accutheme\Main.ascx(14): 
error CS1061: 'portals__default_skins_accutheme_main_ascx' 
does not contain a definition for 'GetScopedService' and 
no accessible extension method 'GetScopedService' accepting 
a first argument of type 
'portals__default_skins_accutheme_main_ascx' 
could be found (are you missing a using directive 
or an assembly reference?)
```

Am I missing a reference to or import of something? If yes, its not obvious to me at the moment. What exactly hooks up the extension method to the UserControl (this)?

Comment: Awesome - you were a bit too fast. Sorry for this
I was in a hurry writing the blog and had to rename the method to avoid confusion, and haven't publish the changes yet. i just did it right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comment Daniel. For fun, before upgrading to v14.1, I tried it with the old name `this.GetService` and it worked. Upgraded to v14.1.0 (released 8 hours ago) and now the Blog's code samples work as expected.

Thank you!!